# how to make this javascript object from php json encode

Tags: javascript, php, json

hello i am trying to figure out how i would ago about pulling information from a database in php and json_encoding it ito a JavaScript object that contains several JavaScript arrays that themselves have children objects and arrays.
below is the JavaScript i need.  ive been playing with embedding arrays into php objects but cant seem to get it to come our correctly.

```
self.navigation = [
    {
        menutext:"Home",
        url:"/"
    },
    {
        menutext:"About",
        url: "#/about",
        submenu:[
        {
            menutext:"Pricing",
        url: "/pricing"
        }
        ]
    }
    ];
```

Comment: what have you tried? post php code.  json_encode() will probably do what you need, might need to tweak the options a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var jsObject = <?php echo json_encode($phparray); ?>;
</script>
```

pretty self-explanatory i think, if you need the object a specific way it's about how you format your php array itself.

To get arrays within objects you use the object key and set it to an array like so:

```
$phpArray = array(
        'magic' => array('elmo')
);
```

json_encoded an array will be within the "magic" object. In order to get the parent item as an array with objects inside i would just fudge it in the variable setting itself like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var jsObject = [<?php echo json_encode($phparray); ?>];
</script>
```

To get submenu into array have you tried the following:

```
$phpArray = array(
'menutext' => 'About',
'url' => '#/about',
'submenu' => array(
    array(
    'menutext' => 'Pricing',
    'url' => '/pricing')
)
);
```

Bit unintuitive I know. Actually to get exactly what you want without fudging it would be:

```
$phpArray = array(
array(
'menutext' => 'Home'
),
array(
'menutext' => 'About',
'url' => '#/about',
'submenu' => array(
    array('menutext' => 'Pricing',
    'url'=> '/pricing')
)
)
);
```

Comment: im sure this is the right anwser but having troubles getting it to make the submenu into an actual array, seems to be the only way i can get angular to read it

Comment: I've edited my answer, should help you out more now ;)

Comment: amazing, missing that second array call lol i have beaten my head against the wall for days.... made me realize i need to learn more about javascript lol